# What do you call an object that defines its methods/fields when it is instantiated?

Tags: java, anonymous

What it called when you have a class body after you create an object and what it's useful for?

Example:

```
public MyObject myObject = new MyObject() /*from here*/{
    void myMethod() {
        //code
   }
};/*to here*/
```

Because usually it just looks like this:

```
public MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
```

Comment: Are you referring to [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called Anonymous Classes.  Check out the docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

It's a way to derive from a class in just the place that you want to use it.